# Voltage regulation threshold

Tags: voltage, remote-control

I am designing a 5V digital circuit and I want to make it generic so the user has some flexibility in the VCC input limits. The problem is, since the MCU has to run at 5V, I have to ensure it will get the 5V, and to do so I can place a LDO or a Linear Regulator (I am avoiding switching regulator because they require more components, and usually not small SMD ones), but both of them CAN NOT be driven at 5V since they have a minimum voltage that has to be greater than the regulated voltage.

Is there a way to still have a regulated VCC input and if the user connect the voltage I just want I wont have any problems?

To be more clear, this will be used in R/C (Remote Controlled), which already have a shared 5V wire, but some R/C use 6V, which could be fine for a LDO, but not if the user connect a 5V directly.

If you need more details, please let me know.

Comment: A circuit schematic would be helpful to clarify what you're trying to do.

Comment: How much PCB space do you have? What is the current required at regulated output? What voltage range will the MCU and supporting circuitry tolerate? Many 5 Volt nominal MCUs work well over a span of 4.5-5.1 Volts, and some can span <3.3 to >5.0 volts. LDOs need a minimal voltage headroom to work with, none work with zero-headroom switch-over that I know of.

Comment: A MOSFET will have 1 mV of drop per milli-Ohm of Rdson at 1 smp. 10 milliOhm and lower MOSFETS are available allowing 10 mV drop at 1A and 1 mV at 100 mA. You can build your own custom targeted LDO around this capability. If the circuit starts wit the MOSFET not fully on so that the voltage can ramp up to the desired level it will work without risk of damaging the target device.

Comment: I dont have a schematic yet...it's just a PIC18F2550 controling a H-Bridge drive IC. Everything SMD, so I whant to save space on the PCB.
Since it is a H-Bridge, the user can come with many inputs on the H-Bridge, but the PIC will be using the R/C input to take it's power from, but I just wanted to give the user the ability to use the complete power of the batteries if he wanted to...

Comment: **BEWARE** that the "5v" is likely to be 4.8v ranging down to 4.5v or lower as most receiver packs are NiCd or NiMH rather than disposable batteries.  So if you are going for something that will tolerate a lower voltage, you probably want to design for 3.3v after regulation.  Also consider that lithium batteries are taking over, so consider if you can support usage on 1 or 2 of those cells.

Comment: @ChrisStratton thanks, but I am using the receiver's BEC (Battery Elimination Circuit) regulated 5V to power the PIC...the LDO will be there just as a safety component, in case the BEC goes nuts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working on the assumption that the MCU in question will operate down to 4.7 volts or so, the simplest option is to use a LDO with a very small headroom requirement, e.g. the [LP38691-ADJ/LP38693-ADJ](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lp38691-adj.pdf) (250 mV at 500 mA output).

Your circuit would be designed to work at 4.7 volts, and the LDO would be adjusted for this voltage. Input voltage can then range from 4.95 volts through 10 volts.

In practice, if the MCU in question can cope with Vcc of 4.5 volts, that provides you a better margin of reliability: Trim the LDO for 4.55 volts, and things will remain stable even if the input 5 volt line sags down to 4.8 volts, as it might under motors or other load.

Another approach is to switch over to a 3.3 Volt MCU, and suitable level translation logic running off the unregulated 5-6 Volt line for those parts on the board which absolutely can not work with 3.3 volt logic. Often 5 volt logic parts accept 3.3 Volt input fine (check the datasheet), and there are 3.3 Volt MCUs ([PIC18F45J10](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en024619), [MSP430F51x2](http://www.ti.com/product/msp430f5172)) which are 5 Volt tolerant on selected GPIOs.

Comment: I am using a PIC18F2550, I am not sure how it behaves under 5V since I am using the PLL to drive it to 48MHz and I didn't understand completely the graph on the datasheet about frequency and volts...what's your opinion?

Comment: @mFeinstein The PIC18F2550 microcontroller is fully specified from 4.2 Volts to 5.5 Volts, and uses an internal voltage regulator for voltage-sensitive functions (such as USB). So it should work fine across that voltage range. Set your LDO to 4.4 Volts or so, and you have a safety margin at both ends.

Comment: Great! Thank you!
Which LDO do you recommend? Is there a better manufacture? Or a common used part? I am going for SMD, so a small one that can handle the PIC + 2 LEDs is fine..

Comment: @mFeinstein Answer has said that the LP38691-ADJ/LP38693-ADJ LDOs are there with 250 mv headroom, datasheet link says both have option SMDs.

Comment: @mFeinstein Heh, like the gentleman said above, those two are good options ($1.62 single unit price at DigiKey): Also, Texas Instruments is awesome at FedExing out free samples world-wide, so you could get request a couple of pieces and start trying them out pretty fast.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh, maybe this is a matter for another post, but what are the right specs to look at when I am choosing a LDO? I am using TI selection too, but I am getting results as:
Fixed Output: 5V
V(min): 3V
How I will suply 3V and get at the end 5V? The LDO doesnt Step-Up right?

Comment: @mFeinstein Yes, might be good for another question. I'm not quite sure what you mean, a screenshot would help. No, LDOs do not step up, but boost regulators do. Some of them are available in 3-pin SIP modules similar to a 7805, just thicker - and no additional inductor needed.

Comment: @mFeinstein I could be wrong about boost regulator modules that do not need external parts: I'm able to find only buck modules meeting that description, by a cursory search.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh look at this website:
http://www.ti.com/paramsearch/docs/parametricsearch.tsp?family=analog&familyId=659&uiTemplateId=NODE_STRY_PGE_T

then select "Fixed Output Options (V)" to 5V, and look at the table...there are 5V fixed outputs witha  Vin of 3V for example...am I confusing things?

Comment: @mFeinstein TI's parametric search is odd sometimes. I use it to shortlist parts, then open the datasheet of each, and look for the "Dropout voltage" option. e.g. for fixed Vo = 5V and IoutMax >= 100 mA, first option [TPS73133-EP](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps73133-ep.pdf) actually refers to a family of parts, with various fixed Vo values from 1.2 V to 5 V. This datasheet lists "Vout Max = 5.5 – VDO", and "Vdo = 30 to 100 mV".

Comment: So Vout Max will be 5.5-0.03 = 5.47V ?

Comment: @mFeinstein For that particular LDO, 5.5 - 0.1 = 5.4V, taking worst-case Vdo. However, you would adjust Vout to be 4.4 volts, and not even need to come close to VoutMax.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh Oh yes, it's late in here, so I thought wrong about the worst case hehe.
Thank you very much my friend, I am new to LDOs, you have been very helpful!

Comment: The minimum dropout idea is unworkable with a battery pack that may be as low as 4.5v to being with.

Comment: @ChrisStratton The power input is from a 5 Volt uBEC I believe. ... and I notice this has been clarified by the OP, so the downvote appears a bit uncalled for.